# UDP sendto() No buffer space available

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c, udp

I'm trying to create an iOS application that sends data over UDP continuously over wifi/3G network.
I have an issue when I launch my app over 3G network after like 10 seconds I get this message :

```
sendto() : No buffer space available
```

It's not that a big deal because my app still works well BUT when I quit the app, I guess my buffer                                                                stays full because I can't use 3G anymore (I have to wait some time or reboot my phone)

Is there a way to flush this buffer before I quit my app ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you're hitting the outbound bandwidth limit. If your app does this continuously while in use, isn't that going to make it very expensive for users to run? Most mobile users, I would guess, are on some kind of metered plan where they pay for transferred data.

I would guess that closing the socket normally before exiting should flush it first, since you've requested the data to be sent after all, but sometimes UDP sockets don't try very hard to deliver the data (since they are "lossy"), perhaps that's what's happening in your case too.

Comment: It's a streaming app so yeah it costs a lot of bandwidth. But more and more people have like 3Go data per month - it's more than 70h of poor video quality. Indeed I call close(sock) before closing my App  without much success